# We've eaten at that restaurant in recent years

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Could you please tell me whether the following sentence

> We've eaten at that restaurant in recent years.

is grammatically correct and sounds natural? Is that the correct  usage of the present perfect?

Comment: Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct, easy to understand, and sounds normal.

Comment: @J.Taylor, since there's no real way to make this a more detailed answer, you might as well add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @J. Taylor said,

> Yes, the sentence is grammatically correct, easy to understand, and sounds normal.